# Createdatetime columns is populating as 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql

I have created one table and inserting values in the table from a csv file using a python code .The createdatetime and updatedatetime columns are set to default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.But when I am populating the data updatedatetime  is populating the correct value but createdatetime  is populating as 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Here is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `fico_details` (
  `adf_contact_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sf_contact_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `BirthDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zipcode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SSN` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State2` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zipcode2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customerinput` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AddrDiscrepancyFlg` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Permid` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score_date` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason_code_1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason_code_2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason_code_3` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason_code_4` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreateDateTime` TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UpdateDateTime` TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `SSN` (`SSN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=876800 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

please help me to solve it.

Comment: Share your sample program and sample data of CSV to check actual problem in it

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but you may want to consider looking at your identifier naming. Half of your fields are CamelCase and half are lowercase_underscored. All I want to do with this code is fix that (and use `DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GetDate()` instead of timestamp).

Answer (score -1):

I am working on same thing these days.
First of all I use timestamp as the datatype as apart from having datetime capabilities, it has MANY usable functions as a string as well as timestamp datatype.

I got the SAME issue as yours, what I did was alter my table was created, I would click on ALTER table using any Db tool (SQLYog in my case) and then Delete the 0000-00-00 00:00:00 value and uncheck the Not NULL check box.

This issue gets resolved EVERYTIME (whenever I create same type of table/columns)after this simple one step.

Hope this helps you too, let me know if anything still bothers you....!!

Comment: This simple step worked wonders for me as I have to do this only once.